# Computer Science Original Position Paper Questions

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I am submitting a research paper to a conference for the first time. I will be submitting an 'original position paper'. I believe this is what the paper should consist of:

- 50% background research (literature survey - summarizing the previous works/pointing out their drawbacks or areas not covered by them)
- 20% my new idea
- 30% implications of my idea and future work

Is this approach correct?

Comment: Do you have an advisor? Did you try to ask him/her? This may greatly vary across different venues, or even within a venue.

Comment: "Computer Science Position Paper". I have never heard of such a thing before. And what is this? "Implications of my idea". What does that mean? Is your work already done and finished? If yes, this is not a position paper. If not, and the idea is in preliminary stage why do you want to present it before it is done? Unless, we are talking about a PHD proposal - workshops which are suitable forums for preliminary ideas.

Comment: I've heard of computer science position papers. What are the constraints on the paper? Is it 1 page LNCS? Or 4 pages ACM? The size makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your discipline and on the conference in a fundamental way. If your advisor (or anyone you know) has submitted this kind of manuscript to this particular conference before, you should absolutely ask him/her for tips and suggestions.

You should also go to the conference's web site and look for their requirements for submission. Nearly all such organizations have a page or document that lists their requirements for submission. In the unlikely event that there is *no* such information at all, or in the more likely event that you still have questions after reading it carefully, look on that document or on the website for a submission contact person who will be able to answer your question(s).

Good luck!

Comment: Why do you assume that something has been accepted?